# MySQL перестала отвечать на запросы

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сегодня в обед все отлично работало, сейчас захожу проверить и вижу пустой сайт. Сразу побежал смотреть `error_log`. Вижу там такие ошибки:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '...' (using password: YES) in ....
>
> [PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   boolean given in ...
>   PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean
>   given in ...

Понимаю, что нет подключения с БД и оно не дает доступ, но проблема точно не в отправляемых параметрах, там все верно. Потому что работало же, а я ничего не менял. В `phpmyadmin` с базами все в порядке. В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

**UPD:** Если делаю простой запрос таким кодом:

```php
<?php
$dblink = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

if($dblink)
echo 'Соединение установлено.';
else
die('Ошибка подключения к серверу баз данных.');

$selected = mysql_select_db($database, $dblink);
if($selected)
echo ' Подключение к базе данных прошло успешно.';
else
die(' База данных не найдена или отсутствует доступ.');
?>
```

То показывает, что соединение установлено и к БД подключение прошло успешно.

Comment: проблема точно в параметрах подключения. проверяйте на сервере через SSH mysql -uYOUR_USER -p YOUR_DB

Comment: @tcpack4, ничего же не менялось. Днем это работало, а сейчас нет...

Comment: данная ошибка обозначает, что сервер работает, но зайти под этим юзером и паролем не может. Если проблемы со стабильностью - то будет  Mysql has gone away.

Comment: @tcpack4, добавил проверку в вопрос. Простое подключение срабатывает.

Comment: найдите строчку где PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045) . в ошибке указан файл и номер строки и сделайте var_dump все аргументов к mysqli_connect. 110% параметры подключения различаются.

Comment: То есть через phpmyadmin сейчас с тем же логином и паролем заходит? А если просто открыть сайт - то ошибка подключения? У вас обычный хостинг? Или VPS? Есть доступ для перезагрузки MySQL-сервера? Или сайт локально?

Comment: И в параметре server у вас что? localhost?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, все непонятным способом снова заработало и никакой ошибки как будто и не было(ничего не менял). Видимо у компании, у которой беру услуги были проблемы

Comment: Компания случайно не 1gb? Обычные проблемы для shared-хостингов)

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Нет, multihost :)

Comment: Проверяйте базу на изменения. Возможно по какой-то причине они откат делали своего сервера. А вообще лучше у них спросить, если есть данные важные. И не забывайте удаленный бекап делать :)

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, спасибо за советы. С информацией вроде как все в порядке. Вопросы уже задал в их поддержку

Answer (score 0):

Видимо надо ответить на свой вопрос, раз проблема была решена. 
Предполагаю, что проблема была на уровне shared хостинга, никакие изменения настроек не помогали(чего я только не пробовал) и спустя какое-то время все снова заработало. И ошибок никаких уже нет(все параметры оказались правильными). Поэтому жду ответа компании на мои письма и советую, если вдруг у кого-то случится похожая ситуация, писать в тех поддержку.